# Windows Python: sphinx-build.exe file "disappears"

Tags: python, windows, makefile, python-sphinx

The question is "why won't Sphinx work in Windows?" or "why is sphinx-build.exe missing after a proper install?".

I have one answer, here it is.

We use Sphinx to generate Python docs. It works fine in Linux,  but yesterday it stopped working in Windows.  I've seen bug reports about "sphinx-build.exe" being a missing file.

I got to the bottom of the problem today on a Windows system. The symptom of the problem is that an executable "sphinx-build.exe" vanishes from the file system after a failed make.

I've repeated this cycle several times. Same happens if I am in a virtual environment

Here is my Scripts directory after removing and re-installing Sphinx:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\PJPJPJ\apps\python38\Scripts


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        3/10/2021  12:40 PM         106348 sphinx-apidoc.exe
-a----        3/10/2021  12:40 PM         106362 sphinx-autogen.exe
-a----        3/10/2021  12:40 PM         106347 sphinx-build.exe
-a----        3/10/2021  12:40 PM         106352 sphinx-quickstart.exe
```

An attempt to run sphinx-build fails:

```
PS C:\Users\PJPJPJ\GIT\HRB\ml_ita\ml_ita\packages\ita\docs> make html
sh: /c/Users/PJPJPJ/apps/python38/Scripts/sphinx-build: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:20: html] Error 126
PS C:\Users\PJPJPJ\GIT\HRB\ml_ita\ml_ita\packages\ita\docs>
```

After that, the listing shows the file has disappeared:

```
PS C:\Users\PJPJPJ\apps\python38> ls .\Scripts\sphinx*


    Directory: C:\Users\PJPJPJ\apps\python38\Scripts


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        3/10/2021  12:40 PM         106348 sphinx-apidoc.exe
-a----        3/10/2021  12:40 PM         106362 sphinx-autogen.exe
-a----        3/10/2021  12:40 PM         106352 sphinx-quickstart.exe
```

I did this over and over, thinking I was going crazy. On the 8th time, I noticed a warning was coming up just for a moment on the bottom right.  This explained it. "Crowdstrike detected malicious software". The thing pops up and disappears so quickly I cannot copy down whole message to show you whole thing.

Ach. Corporate antivirus controls.

Comment: You should be able to get around this by going to the site-packages of your Sphinx installation and running the `.py` file entry point instead of the `.exe` executable. Look at `C:\path_to_your_venv\Lib\site-packages\sphinx\cmd\build.py` to see if it's there. Then you can alter your make file, change `SPHINXBUILD` to have Python call Sphinx as a module instead of Windows running the executable directly. (Off course, if you have the possibility to white-list the executable in the anti-virus that can even be easier). Although for debugging running as a module can actually be simpler at times.

Comment: Anther option is to run `python -m sphinx` as equivalent of `sphinx-build.exe`.

Comment: @LexLi I confirm that if I change the make.bat file like so, this works!  `set SPHINXBUILD=python -m sphinx`. You should write that as an answer and I'll upvote it.  Am still exploring @bax_coder's answer.

Comment: @bad_coder Do you mean to make same change that I wrote in my comment to @LexLi? I did not understand exactly what you were proposing, but if you write it as an answer I'll upvote it.  Just be explicit on what a bone-head ought to do.

Comment: @pauljohn32 I posted an answer that tries to pinpoint what's at play and explains the possible solutions. It may seem lengthy but it's an easy and engaging read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a clear picture of what we're talking about lets look at the list of relevant file/directories (only files relevant to the case at hand are featured).

```
C:\>tree PATH_TO_YOUR_VENV_OR_INSTALLATION

C:\PATH_TO_YOUR_VENV_OR_INSTALLATION
├───Include
├───Lib
│   └───site-packages
│              └───sphinx
│                  ├──__main__.py
│                  ├───cmd
│                  │     ├──build.py
│                  │     └──quickstart.py
│                  └───ext
│                        └──apidoc.py
└───Scripts
         ├──activate.bat
         ├──sphinx-apidoc.exe
         ├──sphinx-build.exe
         └──sphinx-quickstart.exe
```

Now, the executable `.exe` files (that your anti-virus is deleting) are basically mappings to the corresponding `.py` modules (all featured above). These are the equivalent to setuptools [`entry_points`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html?entry-points-and-automatic-script-creation#entry-points-and-automatic-script-creation) and you can see this implemented in [Sphinx's `setup.py` on GitHub](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3.x/setup.py#L234).

The solution of calling `python -m sphinx` corresponds to the following:

> 1.1.1. Interface options
>
> [-m <module-name>](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)
>
> Package names (including namespace packages) are also permitted. When a package name is supplied instead of a normal module, the interpreter will execute <pkg>.__main__ as the main module.

In reality by calling `python -m sphinx` you are executing the Sphinx package as if it were a module, this can be verified if you make the call without any arguments on the command line, the result would be:

> usage: __main__.py [OPTIONS] SOURCEDIR OUTPUTDIR [FILENAMES...]
> __main__.py: error: the following arguments are required: sourcedir, outputdir, filenames

So lets look at the contents of the above featured `__main__.py` file:

```py
import sys

from sphinx.cmd.build import main

sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

This is the reason I'm writing a more extensive answer (also for future readers), because if your anti-virus decides to also delete `sphinx-apidoc.exe` and `sphinx-quickstart.exe` simply using `python -m sphinx` won't solve those further problems.

Finally, when you run `make html` you are executing the makefile that was (most likely) generated using `sphinx-quickstart`. If your project has the usual file/directory layout ([with `source` separate from `build`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-quickstart.html#cmdoption-sphinx-quickstart-sep)) it will look like this:

```
C:\Your_Project
├───docs
│    ├──build
│    ├──source
│    ├──make.bat
│    └──makefile
│
├───src
(...)
```

Lets include the 4 relevant lines of the above `makefile` to get a clear picture of what's happening before we wrap-up the explanation:

```
SPHINXOPTS    ?=
SPHINXBUILD   ?= sphinx-build
SOURCEDIR     = source
BUILDDIR      = build
```

The 2 directories `SOURCEDIR` and `BUILDDIR` correspond to the `build` and `source` directories featured above. What is happening when you invoke the `makefile` running `make html` is invoking `sphinx-build` with the following signature (from the documentation):

> [sphinx-build](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html)
>
> Synopsis
>
> sphinx-build [options] <sourcedir> <outputdir> [filenames …]

Possible solutions:

**Solution 1**. You can change the line corresponding to `SPHINXBUILD   ?= sphinx-build` to `SPHINXBUILD   ?= python -m sphinx` it will work and you'll be executing the sphinx package **as a module** (as shown by the `__main__.py` file).

**But** that doesn't solve (nor address) the potential problem if your anti-virus decides to delete the remaining executable `.exe` files (and you also want to execute those). **Besides**, there are a number of scenarios where you'll want to avoid using the makefile altogether, so giving the full explanation addresses all these scenarios.

**Solution 2**. You can build with Sphinx directly without the executable or the makefile.

When you call `make html` you usually do so on the path that has the makefile (in the above examples you'd call it from the `/docs` directory). So lets consider 2 possible paths from where to invoke when not using the makefile:

- Calling from the `/docs` directory. You can pass the `source` and `build` directories relative to where you're executing, like this:

  `python C:\PATH_TO_YOUR_VENV_OR_INSTALLATION\Lib\site-packages\sphinx\cmd\build.py -b html source build/html`
- Calling from anywhere. You'd use full paths for `source` and `build` like this:

  `python C:\PATH_TO_YOUR_VENV_OR_INSTALLATION\Lib\site-packages\sphinx\cmd\build.py -b html C:/Your_Project/docs/source C:/Your_Project/docs/build/html`

Which boils down to calling Python with [`sphinx-build`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#sphinx-build) **as a script** (more precisely `build.py`) passing in the full paths explicitly. (And the same method would also apply for the other executables).

Here 2 important notes are necessary:

1. If you're building HTML the [`-b`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-b) option is necessary, so you'll pass in `-b html` in the options list.
2. On Windows the path separators are backslashes `\` but the arguments you are passing into Sphinx need to use forwardslashes `/` as separators.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the sphinx Python package, you have two options to execute it,

- Execute `sphinx-build.exe`
- Or execute `python -m sphinx`

So before you learn exactly what deleted the former, you can try to use the latter as an alternative way.