# Run python module commands on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, windows-terminal

I installed Sphinx using `pip install sphinx` command in Windows Terminal and I want to run `sphinx-quickstart` to make documentation in my `docs` directory but it doesn't work.

I get this error instead:

```
sphinx-quickstart : The term 'sphinx-quickstart' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

If I try to run it via GitBash or using `py` or `python` at the beginning that says:

```
\path_to_python\python.exe: can't open file '\My_working_directory\docs\sphinx-quickstart': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The reason this is happening is because Sphinx should be installed in your virtual environment and you have to [activate the virtual env](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) on the terminal where you are using it. After that the terminal will find  [`sphinx-quickstart`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-quickstart.html#sphinx-quickstart) tool wherever you run it. If you want to check where it is see the instructions [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66574786).

Comment: Is `python_installation_folder\Scripts` in your PATH?

Comment: I followed the instruction and created directory. I launched ```.bat``` file and now terminal has ```(tutorial-env)``` at the beginning that's good. But if I try to call ```sphinx-quickstart``` in my directory it says me: 'sphinx-quickstart' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Oil, yes that is

Comment: Ok it worked, I don't know why Sphinx didn't appear in Scripts directory in python installation folder and I needed to install again in virtual env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to create simple virtual environment and you will able to install packages you want and run it.

Just create folder and run command to create virtual environment then just activate it using `.bat` file.

Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) but it can differ in future versions of Python.